# Capturing multiple parameters in a url to a single array in Struts 2

Tags: url, parameters, struts2

This is my `struts.xml` class:

```xml
<action name="{param1}/{param2}/{param3}" 
        class="myactionclass"  
        method="execute"> 
     <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
</action>
```

So in my action class, I have to create three `String` objects `String param1, param2, param3` (and add getter and setter methods) to get the `param` values. What I want to do is, instead of creating 3 different String objects, create a single String array and store the `param` values into the String array using the setter.

How do I achieve this in my action class ?

Comment: Have you tried exactly that: to use an array?

Comment: Can you explain more clearly what exactly you want to do?

Comment: Haven't tried using an array. Want to know if its possbile.

Comment: more clearly? Well, I want to have a String array say params[] that stores param1, param2 and param3 values from the url

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Populating an array in Struts2 using parameters in query-string is pretty easy.

In your Action declare the array with corresponding setter

```
private String[] fruits;

public void setFruits(String[] fruits) {
    this.fruits = fruits;
}
```

This request will populate your `fruits` array

> /myactionuri?fruits=apple&fruits=banana&fruits=peach

But with static parameters this mechanism doesn't seem to work in the same way.

I found this solution, maybe not as elegant, but it works.
In your `struts.xml`:

```
<!-- warning: this pattern matches all requests with 3 tokens separated by slashes -->
<action name="*/*/*" class="com.xxx.MyAction" > 
     <param name="f1">{1}</param>
     <param name="f2">{2}</param>
     <param name="f3">{3}</param>
</action>
```

And in your Action:

```
private String[] fruits = new String[3]; //need to be initiated

public void setF1(String f1) {
    this.fruits[0] = f1;
}

public void setF2(String f2) {
    this.fruits[1] = f2;
}

public void setF3(String f3) {
    this.fruits[2] = f3;
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell which parameter will go to which index in the array.

```xml
<action name="{param[0]}/{param[1]}/{param[2]}" class="myactionclass"> 
    <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Action (using array):

```java
private String[] param = new String[3];
// getter and setter
```

Instead of array you can use `List`, then there is no need to initialize it in the action.

Action (using `List`):

```java
private List<String> param;
// getter and setter
```

`Map` is also an option.

Action (using `Map`):

```java
private Map<String, String> param;
// getter and setter
```

struts.xml (using `Map` in action):

```xml
<action name="{param['p1']}/{param['p2']}/{param['p3']}" class="myactionclass"> 
     <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Comment: Caution with the `List` solution if you plan to put a simple `add()` in the setter : interceptor stacks with more than one call to `params` are quite common and list goes out of control

Comment: @fustaki Keep getters and setters clean. There is no need to put add method into setter.